# I want to load the multiple Kafka messages to multiple HDFS folders in Nifi

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi

Currently I am using ConsumeKafkaRecord, Merge Content and PutHDFS to load the data from kafka to Hive. We need to automate this for multiple kafka topics. Is there any way to do it in nifi.

Eg : If I give topic names as abc,xyz the data from abc topic should be moved to /abc and data from xyz should be moved to /xyz folder.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 4):

The [ConsumeKafkaRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-kafka-2-0-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.kafka.pubsub.ConsumeKafkaRecord_2_0/) processor writes an attribute named `kafka.topic` that contains the name of the topic where records are from.

And the **directory** parameter of [PutHDFS](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-hadoop-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.hadoop.PutHDFS/index.html) supports expression language.

so, you could specify something like `/${kafka.topic}` in it

Comment: thanks daggett. We are able to transfer the data to multiple folders but it is creating very small files in hdfs. Is there any way to do avoid it. We tried using Merge Content but it is merging all the topics data.

Comment: sounds like another question.  you have to ask a new questio: show the attributes of a small file , parameters of merge content processor, and expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your second part of the question, you can merge files (using mergeContent) based on the 'kafka.topic' attribute. This way you can merge content of different topics using one processor. (Data of every topic will be merged only with the data of that particular topic)

You can then route the files to different directories in HDFS by mentioning the path as "hdfs://${your-hdfs-path}/${kafka.topic}"

Let me know if you need more assistance!